# How to find multiple values from one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```html
SELECT *
FROM `engine4_user_fields_values`
WHERE (field_id = 3) AND (value = 'test7') AND (field_id = 4)
  AND (value = 'test7') AND (field_id = 13) AND (value = 'Hemraj')


field_id | value
-----------------------------
3  | test7
4  | test7
13  | Hemraj
```

How to find this values?

When I use `or` operator it's showing two values or one value.
My requirement is if not found any of this one then can't display.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT Value 
FROM `engine4_user_fields_values`
GROUP BY Value
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM `engine4_user_fields_values`
WHERE 
  (field_id = 3 AND value = 'test7') OR 
  (field_id = 4 AND value = 'test7') OR 
  (field_id = 13 AND value = 'Hemraj')
```

Comment: its showing two values when one value not matching.

Comment: My requirement is if not found any of this one then can't display.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see if all the values are there:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 3 THEN 'ALL PRESENT' ELSE 'MISSING FIELD' END)
FROM `engine4_user_fields_values`
WHERE (field_id = 3 AND value = 'test7') OR 
      (field_id = 4 AND value = 'test7') OR 
      (field_id = 13 AND value = 'Hemraj')
```

Comment: if all present how to display this values?

Comment: @HemrajPal . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?